# How to check the quantity availability in SAP from Salesforce?

Tags: integration, sap

I successfully made the salesforce to sap integration and update the SAP item details are displayed in salesforce.

How can I check the order availability in salesforce? I have a quantity field in salesforce order object. Suppose I entered item quantity is 40. I need to check if that quantity of items is availability in SAP system. If available then return success message.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using BAPI_MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY? This is a standard SAP API which lets you check the availability according to various parameters. You need to give it the SAP Plant number, Material number, Unit of Measure as a minimum. You can also specify the checking rule ("A" for orders, "B" for deliveries, "PP" for production planning, etc.). In addition, pass the requested date and requested quantity in the structure WMDVSX.

You'll get back an array of committed quanitites/dates based on the availability in SAP in structure WMDVEX.

Comment: Best would be to check with SAP dev team, maybe they've made some custom BAPIs that adhere to company-specific business logic. And/or there might be another application that already connects to SAP for same purpose, integration point could be reused.